# How to Add an Element and Int in Java

Tags: java

So I have this method wherein I am trying to add "theElement" to elementArray.length so that the size of the elementArray is 6, and not 5. So I tried doing...

```
public boolean addingElement(E theElement) {  
E [] elementArray = new elementArray[5]; 
    if (elementArray.length != 0) { 
        elementArray[ //add theElement and 5 here ]; 
        System.out.println(elementArray.length);
    }
return true; 
}
```

I've tried to do theElement + elementArray.length but I realize that does not work because of the mismatch. What should I do instead?

Comment: If you want to resize your Array, consider `Arrays.copyOf(original, newLength)`

Comment: Can you give an example of an element and what should happen to the array as a result of what you want?

Comment: The element is a random number, but I want to add the "size of the element" to the size of my *newly allocated array after using Arrays.copyOf(original, newLength)

Comment: This is why you typically use a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

In java, Arrays are fixed in size when constructed. So you cannot add a 6th element to a 5-element array.

You must copy the elements into a new array. Either use Arrays.copyOf, or:

```
oldArray; //contains 5 objects, say ints

int [] newArray = new int[oldArray.length*2]; //double the size of oldArray

for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
```

Comment: Right, totally forgot about arrays being a fixed size! Okay so after I do that, how exactly would I add the element and the size of the array to make 6?

Comment: @EyeOfTheOwl just add the element after the code of David, like this `newArray[oldArray.length] = theElement;`